# Find results get removed in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

ok I search for say
`eval()` in a php project to find leaks.

I get 60 hits. I look at the first result and want to see if this is maybe a security leak. I see `eval()` gets called like this `eval($mySpecialVar)` I then search for `$mySpecialVar` I see it is not security problem. Now I want to check the next entry of the `eval()` search result... but it is not there any more. I have now to search again for `eval()` from the very very beginning, and figure out where I was with the 60 results....?!?

is there no more clever way to do it?

**EDIT**

the open in new tab is grayed out for me

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"it's not there anymore"_? Can't you just bring the Find info window back up using Alt+3?

Comment: I searched something again, so the find window has the results of the second search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check "Open in new tab" setting. Its location depends on what search you're using - if it is a text find, the setting is under Result Options section:

[image]

If you're searching for usages, it is in Edit > Find > Find Usages Settings:

[image]

Note that this option is enabled only if you already have some search results displayed. So in your case: you first search for eval(), then before searching for $mySpecialVar you're clicking on "Open in new tab".

Yet another option would be after searching for eval() to pin the search results, so the new search will always be opened in a new tab:

[image]

Comment: I always use the replace in path by standard and just cancel the "you wanna really replace"... the open in new tab is greyed out there, is that for you that case as well? the command is called "Replace in path"

Comment: Find in Path is grayed out as well, the "open in new tab" i cannot click on it

Comment: This option is enabled only if you already have some search results displayed. So in your case: you first search for eval(), then before searching for $mySpecialVar you're clicking on "Open in new tab"